# ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Through combining v$session of my applications seem to have sessions running the following SQL:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE= 'ARABIC' NLS_TERRITORY= 'ARABIC' NLS_CURRENCY= '$' NLS_ISO_CURRENCY= 'ARABIC' NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS= '.,' NLS_CALENDAR= 'ARABIC' NLS_DATE_FORMAT= 'DD-MON-RR' NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE= 'ARABIC' NLS_SORT= 'BINARY'
```

Any idea why these applications are performing these `ALTER SESSION` commands in MYSQL?

Guys, I have a few questions in MySQL, could you please help me.

1. How do I change the NLS_LANGUAGE to ARABIC from the existing one ?
2. By changing the NLS_LANGUAGE to ARABIC , would the MySQL data also
   get changed to ARABIC ? What does NLS_LANGUAGE control MySQL?